# kube-system pods core-dns and dashboard are pending

Tags: kubernetes-dashboard

```
[root@master /]# kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-97vkp                         0/1     Pending   0          17h
kube-system   pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-p7mnl                         0/1     Pending   0          17h
kube-system   pod/etcd-master.pronteelabs.com                      1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-master.pronteelabs.com            1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-master.pronteelabs.com   1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-r2rp8                      1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xp25f                      1/1     Running   1          49m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-k4hw5                                 1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-nrzrv                                 1/1     Running   0          49m
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-master.pronteelabs.com            1/1     Running   0          17h
kube-system   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-7c54d59f66-9w5b7            0/1     Pending   0          45m

NAMESPACE     NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                                                                                           AGE
default       service/kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                                                                                                                                           17h
kube-system   service/heapster               ClusterIP   10.98.205.214    <none>        80/TCP                                                                                                                                            45m
kube-system   service/kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP                                                                                                                            17h
kube-system   service/kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.105.192.154   <none>        443/TCP                                                                                                                                           45m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE                                                                                                                          SELECTOR                     AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     2         2         2       2            2           beta                                                                                                                         .kubernetes.io/arch=amd64     17h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           beta                                                                                                                         .kubernetes.io/arch=arm       17h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           beta                                                                                                                         .kubernetes.io/arch=arm64     17h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           beta                                                                                                                         .kubernetes.io/arch=ppc64le   17h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           beta                                                                                                                         .kubernetes.io/arch=s390x     17h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                2         2         2       2            2           beta                                                                                                                         .kubernetes.io/os=linux       17h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                0/2     2            0           17h
kube-system   deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard   0/1     1            0           45m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-5644d7b6d9                2         2         0       17h
kube-system   replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-7c54d59f66   1         1         0       45m
```

Comment: Please consider adding more details indicating the exact problem which you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the logs for the pods in pending state. Also try to describe the pod and see why it is unschedulable ? (Insufficient Resources, Disk pressure, etc). Just by looking at this output it is tough to say. Also tell which version of kubernetes are you using, how many nodes you have, resources available per node, etc.

*After reading your updates:*

Looks like a systemd issue where docker is not able to find the cni settings. Can you try applying a networking on your cluster like weave or flannel, and see if it works?

```
$ kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

Comment: Hi Harsh Prateek

My docker version
[root@master ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-103.git7f2769b.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7f2769b/1.13.1
 Built:           Sun Sep 15 14:06:47 2019
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Comment: kubernetes verison 1.16.0

Comment: i delete the kube-system core-dns 
kubelet get nodes still there are in NOT READY state.
please advise how to install the kube-system core-dns

Comment: kubectl describe node master.pronteelabs.com | grep cni
  Ready            False   Wed, 25 Sep 2019 12:11:16 +0530   Tue, 24 Sep 2019 16:22:04 +0530   KubeletNotReady              runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

Comment: Looks like a systemd issue where docker is not able to find the cni settings. Can you try applying a networking on your cluster like weave or flannel, and see if it works?